# MySQL bug: Does not allow column name keys...Anyone know why?

Tags: php, mysql

I banged my head against the wall for hours trying to understand why I could not complete an OOP insert statement into a MySQL insert table.

In my table I had a column named keys which was not getting inserted into.

I tried a lot of solutions, but then i renamed the column and the error sorted itself out.

Can anybody please tell me why this is occuring?

I am using wampserver 2.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). You have to backtick it if you want to use it:

Like this:

```
insert into `keys` values (val1, val2) etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a [mysql reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). You have to enclose it within ` to use it as column name. But I discourage that, troubles might appear anyway, for example with some libraries.

Answer (score 1):

when your using reserved words you should enclose them inside `backtick`

```
for example `keys`
```